# The function ceil() is ignored

Tags: c

I have a question regarding the ceil() function. I the following code I try to round up by two decimal places in C for the variable monthlyPayment, and the ceil function seems to be ignored in the output. In the image is the output compared to what it is supposed to be.  [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoOBA.png)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#define MONTHS 12

int main()
{
    double principle;
    double rate;
    double numYears;
    double numMonths;
    double monthlyPayment;
    double monthlyRate;

    printf("Welcome to the morgage calculator.\nEnter your principal amount to get started. ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &principle);
    printf("Enter the yearly morgage interest rate ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &rate);
    printf("Enter the number of years ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &numYears);
    numMonths = numYears * MONTHS;
    monthlyRate = rate / MONTHS / 100;
    monthlyPayment = ((monthlyRate) / (1 - pow((1 + monthlyRate), (-numMonths)))* principle);
    monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment * 100;
    ceil(monthlyPayment);
    monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment / 100;
    double toPrince = 0.0;
    double interest = 0.0;
    printf("Your total monthly payment ammount:$ %.2lf\n", monthlyPayment);
    printf("Month\tPrinciple\tInterest\t $ to Principle\n");
        for (int index = 1; index <= numMonths;) {
            interest = principle * monthlyRate;
            toPrince = monthlyPayment - interest;   
            printf("%2d%16.2lf %16.2lf %16.2lf\n", index, principle, interest, toPrince);
            principle = principle - toPrince;
            index++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Refer to documentation of C. ceil() must return a double value. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html

Comment: `ceil()` is a pure function, that is, it returns the computed value, but it does not modify the argument. Maybe you need `monthlyPayment = ceil(monthlypayment);`.

Comment: 1) Using `monthlyPayment = rint(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100;` or `monthlyPayment = round(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100;` is more financially correct.  In that case, the final payment may need to include a few extra cents.  2) Code like `monthlyPayment = ceil(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100;` should round to the nearest 1/100.

Answer (score 1):

`ceil()` does not alter the variable provided it returns the result.
Should be:

```
double result = ceil(var);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can spot the problem by observing that C functions cannot modify their parameters, unless you pass a pointer to whatever you would like to modify. This is the reason behind adding ampersands in calls to `scanf`.

There's no ampersand in `ceil(monthlyPayment)`, and `monthlyPayment` is not a pointer; hence, no modification is possible.

You can fix your round-up code for `monthlyPayment` as follows:

```
monthlyPayment = ceil(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100;
```